# Height in percentage problem in HTML

Tags: html, css

When the following is rendered, the height parameter of image (img) isn't considered. However, if I vary the width in terms of % for example 80%, it resizes and aspect ratio is intact. If I mention height in terms of px it works. Problems occur only for height being in % and in all browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Image" border="0" height="15%" width="100%" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

If we remove "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" from doctype as shown below, % works for height but any padding given to image won't be considered in IE but works fine in rest of browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Image" border="0" height="15%" width="100%" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using YUI 3 api for CSS Reset. While it removes all default padding of browsers, it wont solve my problem. Any workaround available ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following CSS to my CSS file did the trick.

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Thanks me :D