# Html - Image height (percentage) in container

Tags: html, css

my problem is quite simple but I still cannot find the answer for this one...

Say we have two containers containing an Image.

```
<div id="containera">
<div id="containerb">
<img id="imagea" src="image.jpg"/>

</div></div>
```

and we have something like

```
#containera { width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color:blue;}
#containerb { width: 80%; height: 80%; background-color:red;}
#imagea { height:100%; width:auto;}
```

Problem is: The Image height is FULL SCREEN height and NOT 100% containerb (80% of 50% screenheight).

I want the Image to be 100% height of containerb, not 100% height of the screen. 
Weird: If i work with "width", the width is scaled depending on the width of containerb.

Can I somehow restrict the height of the containers so they dont scale the image to 100% screenheight? tried max-height in tons of variations but it did not work in any way...

Thanks, if you have any idea how i could solve this..

Comment: Maybe related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098842/height-in-percentage-problem-in-html?rq=1 ?

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net  Please make a fiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Is placing the img as a background of #containerb an option? Because then you could look into the background-size property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `html, body {width:100%; height:100%;}`

see working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/A9b6Y/